# Select column in json table Typescript angular

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement to select a specific column based on selection.

```
[

{hallTicket:'A1',  studentName :'Shiva',  subject : 'maths',  obtainedMarks : 95,  cutoffmarks : 75,  totalMarks : 100},
{hallTicket:'A1',  studentName :'Shiva',  subject : 'physics',  obtainedMarks : 82,  cutoffmarks : 75,  totalMarks : 100},
{hallTicket:'A1',  studentName :'Shiva',  subject : 'chemistry',  obtainedMarks : 87.5,  cutoffmarks : 75,  totalMarks : 100},
{hallTicket:'A1',  studentName :'Shiva',  subject : 'english',  obtainedMarks : 62.5,  cutoffmarks : 55,  totalMarks : 75},
{hallTicket:'A1',  studentName :'Shiva',  subject : 'social',  obtainedMarks : 63,  cutoffmarks : 55,  totalMarks : 75},
{hallTicket:'A1',  studentName :'Shiva',  subject : 'telugu',  obtainedMarks : 44.5,  cutoffmarks : 35,  totalMarks : 50},

{hallTicket:'B2',  studentName :'Sonu',  subject : 'maths',  obtainedMarks : 92,  cutoffmarks : 75,  totalMarks : 100},
{hallTicket:'B2',  studentName :'Sonu',  subject : 'physics',  obtainedMarks : 88,  cutoffmarks : 75,  totalMarks : 100},
{hallTicket:'B2',  studentName :'Sonu',  subject : 'chemistry',  obtainedMarks : 82.5,  cutoffmarks : 75,  totalMarks : 100},
{hallTicket:'B2',  studentName :'Sonu',  subject : 'english',  obtainedMarks : 64.5,  cutoffmarks : 55,  totalMarks : 75},
{hallTicket:'B2',  studentName :'Sonu',  subject : 'social',  obtainedMarks : 63,  cutoffmarks : 55,  totalMarks : 75},
{hallTicket:'B2',  studentName :'Sonu',  subject : 'telugu',  obtainedMarks : 42,  cutoffmarks : 35,  totalMarks : 50},

{hallTicket:'C3',  studentName :'Sahu',  subject : 'maths',  obtainedMarks : 90,  cutoffmarks : 75,  totalMarks : 100},
{hallTicket:'C3',  studentName :'Sahu',  subject : 'physics',  obtainedMarks : 86,  cutoffmarks : 75,  totalMarks : 100},
{hallTicket:'C3',  studentName :'Sahu',  subject : 'chemistry',  obtainedMarks : 88.5,  cutoffmarks : 75,  totalMarks : 100},
{hallTicket:'C3',  studentName :'Sahu',  subject : 'english',  obtainedMarks : 72,  cutoffmarks : 55,  totalMarks : 75},
{hallTicket:'C3',  studentName :'Sahu',  subject : 'social',  obtainedMarks : 64,  cutoffmarks : 55,  totalMarks : 75},
{hallTicket:'C3',  studentName :'Sahu',  subject : 'telugu',  obtainedMarks : 45,  cutoffmarks : 35,  totalMarks : 50},

 ] ;
```

I want to select "studentName", "subject", "cutoffmarks", then how select from table json array?

Something like query

```
select studentName, subject, cutoffmarks 
from Table
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with angular, this is a pure javascript question. You would want to look into array.map

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(arr.filter(item => {
    return item.hallTicket === `B2` && item.studentName === `Sanou`;
}));
```

Comment: NO i want to query like 
   select studentName,subject,cutoffmarks from table

Answer (score 0):

Please first you need to fix your json because invalidate.

--the keys of json need double quotes, if the value is string also need double quotes for examples this is correct json.

```
[{"hallTicket":"A1",  "studentName" :"Shiva",  "subject" : "maths",  "obtainedMarks" : 95,  "cutoffmarks" : 75,  "totalMarks" : 100} ]
```

I share posible solution:

```
 let json =
      '[{"hallTicket":"A1",  "studentName" :"Shiva",  "subject" : "maths",  "obtainedMarks" : 95,  "cutoffmarks" : 75,  "totalMarks" : 100} ]';

    let data = JSON.parse(json);

    data.forEach(
      (element: { studentName: any; subject: any; cutoffmarks: any }) => {
        this.list.push(element.studentName);
        this.list.push(element.subject);
        this.list.push(element.cutoffmarks);
      }
    );

    console.log('------------------- ' + this.list);
```

Code on stackblitzs [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pfwufy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get certain properties from your object, I would use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and choose the properties wanted:

```js
const table = [{
  hallTicket: 'A1',
  studentName: 'Shiva',
  subject: 'maths',
  obtainedMarks: 95,
  cutoffmarks: 75,
  totalMarks: 100
}, {
  hallTicket: 'A1',
  studentName: 'Shiva',
  subject: 'physics',
  obtainedMarks: 82,
  cutoffmarks: 75,
  totalMarks: 100
} ];

const data = table.map(x => ({
  studentName: x.studentName,
  subject: x.subject,
  cutoffmarks: x.cutoffmarks
}));
console.log(data);
```